# import Json file that is exported form After Effect to unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, after-effects

i create a 2D animation from After effect and export that as a Json file. and i want this Json file to Unity.

how can i do this? is it need a plug in or some thing more?

do you have any body an experience about this?

thanks for your attentions

Comment: thanks . but its not free. is it any solution or file (link) that help me in free way?

Answer (score 1):

After Affects animations are not supported by Unity3D "as is", so you definitely have to use a plugin or write an animation parser yourself. I think that the quickes way is to look at on [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/after-effect-importer-11132) or [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/ae2unity-after-effect-to-unity-animation-44618) plugin from the asset store. They are both paid. May be you can find some free plugins also.